# How to edit Informatica XML Target Definition

Tags: informatica

For some reason my XML Target Definition, which I imported via an XSD file, is in 'read only' mode and I cannot seem to figure out a way to get it into 'edit mode'.

I am using Informatica PowerCenter Version 8.6 HotFix 8

Answer (score 1):

Did you try going to the target designer and right click on Edit XML Definition?

Comment: Thanks. Though I should say that another step that I was missing, and I'm not sure exactly how to explain this, but in the xml target there is like a diagram of the XSD, it looks like a relational database model. I actually had to click on one of the squares and then I was able to add a column.

Comment: Hey buy any chance do you know how to get a target back into the target designer? I know it sounds trivial, but after I cleared my target designer workspace, I cannot for the life of me get my target back in. I tried dragging it, double clicking, right clicking and selecting 'open' but its grayed out. Thanks.

Comment: You probably were trying to drag in a target local to the mapping you are working in.  Go up to Target Instances, its probably in there.